# Polymer: paper-button on-click does not work when the button is created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-2.x

I created 2 buttons. Both have the same on-click. The first is created by writing a html button inside a div. This one works. The second is created by having an empty div with the inner-h-t-m-l property returning the button. This one does not work. Why?

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="x-custom">
    <template>

        <div inner-h-t-m-l="[[getButton()]]"></div>
        <div><paper-button on-click='didClick'>Does Work</paper-button></div>
    </template>

    <script>
        class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'x-custom';
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {}
            }

            getButton() {
                return "<paper-button on-click='didClick'>Does Not Work</paper-button>";
            }

            didClick() {
                alert("Did Click");
            }
        }
        customElements.define(XCustom.is, XCustom);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Due to my searching to find solution, defining inner html, a function does fire properly. But if you explain what exactly you want to do, then there may find a solution. Like assign a function  dynamically.  ??

Comment: @HakanC i did find another way to do what i was trying to do by refactoring how the page works. But i would still like to know why this doesn't